# List groups and number of users in AD using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to pull a list of groups from AD that start with "pegp" and a count of how many users are in each group and performing this action in PowerShell. This script will give me a list of the all the groups, but I also need how many users are in each group:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'pegp*'"

$Output = forEach($group in $groups) {

    Get-ADGroup -Identity $group | Select-Object name

}

$Output | Export-Csv C:\temp\file_test2.csv
```

I then tried this code, but it's not giving me a count of the users in each group and is actually inserting an additional row after each group name in the CSV:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'pegp*'"

$Output = forEach($group in $groups) {

    Get-ADGroup -Identity $group | Select-Object name
    (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group).count
}

$Output | Export-Csv C:\temp\file_test4.csv
```

Since I'm still new to PowerShell and programming in general, I thought I'd reach out to the well of knowledge to help me figure out where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `Get-ADGroup -Identity $group |Select-Object Name,@{Name='MemberCount';Expression={@(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group).Count}}`

Comment: Thanks Mathias! That worked perfectly! I'm not seeing the checkmark to mark this as "Answered" but this has been answered. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll post a proper answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code produces an alternating stream of 1 object with a Name property, and 1 integer, which is why `Export-Csv` is not producing the results you want - it's expecting *uniform* input.

What you'll want to do is produce 1 object with *2 properties* - for that you could use the `Select-Object` cmdlet with a calculated property for the member count:

```
$groupsWithMemberCount = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'pegp*'" |Select Name,@{Name='MemberCount';Expression={@(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_).Count }}

# no need to call Get-ADGroup again, we already have all the information we need
$groupsWithMemberCount |Export-Csv C:\temp\file_test4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Beware that this counts the total number of members (principals AND nested groups).

If you want only users, filter the ouput from `Get-ADGroupMember` based on their `objectClass`:

```
$groupsWithMemberCount = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'pegp*'" |Select Name,@{Name='MemberCount';Expression={@(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ |Where-Object objectClass -eq 'user').Count}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `Get-ADGroup` with `-Properties Member` appears to be getting member count without having to also run `Get-ADGroupMember` for each group. (Which may be "expensive" in some situations.)

Generally, the following code gets a list of groups in a formatted table along with member count:

```
$pattern = "Name -like 'pegp*'"
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter $pattern -Properties Member

$grpData = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        GroupName    = $group.Name
        MemberCount  = $group.Member.Count
    }
}

# Format the group data as a table and display it
$grpData | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

(Note that there's no call to `Get-ADGroupMember`. We are iterating purely within `Get-ADGroup` object.)

We can further shorten the code the way @Mathias R. Jessen did in his answer (thank you!):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'pegp*'" -Properties Member | Select Name,@{Name='MemberCount';Expression={$_.Member.Count }} | Export-Csv C:\temp\file_test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```